# Show ProgressDialog from outside class

Tags: java, android

I want show a ProgressDialog on the current activity from an outside class, other than passing the variable into the outside class or using a static variable like other answered questions. Is it possible? Here is some simple test code that might help illustrate what I want to do:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.test.test2;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonPressed( View view) {
        test2 T2;
        T2 = new test2();
        Log.d("button", "pressed");
        T2.change();
    }
}
```

And test2.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

public class test2 {

ProgressDialog mDialog;

    public void change() {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Testing");
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.show();
    }

}
```

When the button is pressed, the funtion buttonPressed is called which calls the test2 class to show a ProgressDialog on the Main Activity.

I think it all relies on the context in `mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);`, like somehow it needs to be told the current activity? But I'm new to Java so it's just a guess.

Comment: Your assumption is right because `this` refers to the current class. And you need a `Context` for the constructor, which `Activity` is. The answer by programmer23 should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to change the method passing the current Activity as a parameter from Test2:

```
public void change(Context context) {
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mDialog.setMessage("Testing");
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();
}
```

And then in class MainActivity do this call:

```
public void buttonPressed( View view) {
    test2 T2;
    T2 = new test2();
    Log.d("button", "pressed");
    T2.change(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks works great, nice and simple, can't believe I didn't think of that haha!